# Drawing a triangle in CSS

Tags: html, css

I understand that

```
border-top: 50px solid transparent;
```

means the top border will be 50px in thickness, will be solid and will be have no colour.

I also understanding that

```
border-right: 100px solid red;
```

means the right border will be 100px thick  will be solid and will be red.

But I don't understand how...

```
#triangle-left 
{ width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 50px solid transparent;
 border-right: 100px solid red; 
 border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;}
```

can make a triangle pointing to the left?

And help understanding would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS borders actually have diagonal edges.

Illustration:

```
\-------/
|       |
|       |
|       |
/-------\
```

So border-right actually looks like this:

```
/
|
|
|
\
```

With `height:0px`, `border-right` will also have no height thus it will look like this:

```
/
\
```

Now if you use the following css:

```css
#triangle-left{ 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 50px solid transparent; /* this will fill the top gap */
    border-right: 100px solid red; /* this will be the red triangle */
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent; /* this will fill the bottom gap */
}
```

You'll get:

[image: CSS Triangle]

A triangle pointing left.

Comment: To nit-pick your first sentence, the angle is only 45 degrees if the two adjacent borders are the same size.

Comment: @Spudley Yes I've already updated.. as you said it depends on the width-height ratio

Comment: Had to do that because jsfiddle moans